# Rails deploy on aws using puma, capistrano and nginx error - webpage not available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, capistrano, puma

Hi i have a rails app trying to deploy on aws instance

These are my configurations

**config/deploy.rb**

```
lock '3.5.0'

set :application, 'fullpower_tee'
set :repo_url, 'git_repo_url' # Edit this to match your repository
set :branch, :master
set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy2/fullpower_tee'
set :pty, true
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/application.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system public/uploads}
set :keep_releases, 5
set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_version, 'ruby-2.2.1'


set :puma_rackup, -> { File.join(current_path, 'config.ru') }
set :puma_state, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_bind, "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/puma.sock"    #accept array for multi-bind
set :puma_conf, "#{shared_path}/puma.rb"
set :puma_access_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma_error.log"
set :puma_error_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma_access.log"
set :puma_role, :app
set :puma_env, fetch(:rack_env, fetch(:rails_env, 'production'))
set :puma_threads, [0, 8]
set :puma_workers, 0
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true
set :puma_preload_app, false
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'figaro'
gem 'puma'
group :development do
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano3-puma'
  gem 'capistrano-rails', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'
end
```

**Capfile**

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
require "capistrano/setup"

# Include default deployment tasks
require "capistrano/deploy"

require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets' # for asset handling add
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations' # for running migrations
require 'capistrano/puma'

Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

**environments/production.rb**

```
Hadean::Application.configure do
  # Rails 4
  config.eager_load = true
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/environment.rb

  config.force_ssl = true

  # The production environment is meant for finished, "live" apps.
  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css *.js )

  # Add the fonts path
  config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"

  # Precompile additional assets
  config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
  config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js )
  config.assets.precompile += [ 'admin.css',
                                'admin/app.css',
                                'admin/cart.css',
                                'admin/foundation.css',
                                'admin/normalize.css',
                                'admin/help.css',
                                'admin/ie.css',
                                'autocomplete.css',
                                'application.css',
                                'chosen.css',
                                'foundation.css',
                                'foundation_and_overrides.css',
                                'home_page.css',
                                'ie.css',
                                'ie6.css',
                                'login.css',
                                'markdown.css',
                                'myaccount.css',
                                'normalize.css',
                                'pikachoose_product.css',
                                'product_page.css',
                                'products_page.css',
                                'shopping_cart_page.css',
                                'signup.css',
                                'site/app.css',
                                'sprite.css',
                                'tables.css',
                                'cupertino/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css',# in vendor
                                'modstyles.css', # in vendor
                                'scaffold.css' # in vendor
                                ]

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # if ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY'].present?
  #   config.action_controller.asset_host = "//#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
  # end

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile"

  # For nginx:
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'

  # If you have no front-end server that supports something like X-Sendfile,
  # just comment this out and Rails will serve the files
  config.cache_store = :memory_store
  #config.cache_store = :dalli_store

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = SyslogLogger.new

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Disable Rails's static asset server
  # In production, Apache or nginx will already do this
  config.serve_static_files = true
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
      :storage => :s3,
      :s3_credentials => {
          :bucket => 'fullpowertee',
          :access_key_id => 'AWS_KEY',
          :secret_access_key => 'AWS_SECRET'
      },
      :s3_region => 'Oregon'
  }
  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and javascripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'ror-e.herokuapp.com' }
  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

end
```

On the AWS Instance server I have

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
upstream app {
  # Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
  server unix:/home/deploy2/fullpower_tee/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  root /home/deploy2/fullpower_tee/current/public;

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection '';
    proxy_pass http://app;
  }

  location ~ ^/(assets|fonts|system)/|favicon.ico|robots.txt {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

I am able to successfully deploy using the capistrano and i get the success message from the capistrano that the server is up and running

and also i can see from

**/home/deploy2/fullpower_tee/shared/log/puma_error.log**

```
* Inherited unix:///home/deploy2/fullpower_tee/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock
* Restarting...
Refreshing Gemfile
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.4.0 (ruby 2.2.1-p85), codename: Owl Bowl Brawl
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 8
* Environment: production
* Daemonizing...
=== puma startup: 2016-06-12 08:44:07 +0000 ===
```

Also i have already done the sudo service nginx restart after the deployment

now everything seems to be fine but when i try to hit the public ip of the AWS Instance it stucks on loading and the browser throws the error

```
This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Please Help me out i am stuck into this issue since a day

Comment: Please add the OS and firewall setting

Comment: Try changin `server_name localhost;` to something like `server_name your_public_domain_name`. Also, can you provide a link for your application? Maybe it's a DNS error.

Comment: till now i have the public ip as 52.36.40.225 do i need to put this in the server_name ?

Comment: @user4965201what kind of Operation System you use? Centos, Ubuntu ?

Comment: i am using ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I suggest you to open a 80 port maybe  this can help `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: What are the rules in your EC2 security group?

Comment: HTTP
TCP
80
0.0.0.0/0 and

SSH
TCP
22
0.0.0.0/0